# Albumentations on Google Colab : module 'albumentations' has no attribute 'SomeOf'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, albumentations

Originally, I posted this in [Albumentation's Github issues listing](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/issues/1173#issue-1251616985)

I used Albumentations on my local machine to do data augmentation using the latest version `1.1.0` through a regular pip install into my local virtual environment. Everything is working fine in the lcoal machine. When I upload my backend code to Google Colaboratory. Up until now, I can't find the `SomeOf` attribute. It says : module 'albumentations' has no attribute 'SomeOf'.

I upgraded my OpenCV to fit the requirement, just in case! I performed some upgrades, force reinstalls and compiled from source installations on **albumentations**. The pip is saying that the installed version is truly **1.1.0** but the `print(albumentations.__version__)` is giving me version **0.1.12** instead.

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior: on Google Colab Pro

> 1. !pip install -q -U albumentations (tried other methods as mentioned above)
> 2. !echo "$(pip freeze | grep albumentations) is successfully installed"
> 3. import albumentations as A
> 4. print(A.**version**)

### Expected behavior

To have version **1.1.0** from the print at step 5 instead of **0.1.12**

### Additional context

Here's the transform composition that I've defined in my backend code.

```py
TRANSFORM = A.Compose(
        [
            # Geometric transforms 30%
            A.OneOf(
                [
                    A.HorizontalFlip(),
                    A.Rotate(limit=90+45, border_mode=BORDER_CONSTANT),
                ], p=0.3
            ),
            # Color related transforms 60%
            A.SomeOf(
                [
                    A.RandomBrightness(limit=0.5),
                    A.HueSaturationValue(
                        hue_shift_limit=0,
                        sat_shift_limit=35,
                        val_shift_limit=0
                    ),
                    A.RandomBrightnessContrast(
                        brightness_limit=0.4,
                        contrast_limit=0.25,
                        p=0.2
                    ),
                    # Weather related transforms
                    A.OneOf(
                            [
                                A.RandomRain(p=0.05),
                                A.RandomShadow(p=0.1),
                                A.RandomSunFlare(p=0.1)
                            ], p=0.5
                        ),
                ], 2, p=0.6
            ),
            # Camera related transforms 10%
            A.SomeOf(
                [
                    # Noise related transforms
                    A.OneOf(
                        [
                            A.GaussNoise(),
                            A.MultiplicativeNoise()
                        ], p=0.5
                    ),
                    # Blur related transforms
                    A.OneOf(
                        [
                            A.Blur(blur_limit=3, p=0.25),
                            A.MedianBlur(blur_limit=3, p=0.25),
                            A.GaussianBlur(p=0.25),
                            A.MotionBlur(p=0.25),
                        ], p=0.5
                    ),
                ], 2, p=0.1
            ),
        ]
    )
```

I stumbled on this notebook by @benihime91 [tensorflow-example.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/albumentations-team/albumentations_examples/blob/colab/tensorflow-example.ipynb) and issues are also appearing in the same context as mine appart that the error is related to OpenCV dependencies that I already upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: If you're using tensorflow, then you should use official augmentation, [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/). FYI, interestingly, the [`keras_cv`](https://keras.io/guides/keras_cv/) is coming with lots of vectorized preprocessing layers.

Comment: I think that I solved the problem. The fitting version right now is 1.0.3 and it requires opencv version 4.5.5.64. Now I can focus on the depreciated transforms and upgrade pillow to a higher version than 8.1.2. Because I am getting few warnings (but not errors). I will share the answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried changing the version installation and it worked

`!pip install -q opencv-python==4.5.5.64`

`!pip install -q --force-reinstall albumentations==1.0.3`

It is also recommended to update Pillow to a recent version.